# grails object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: grails

I know that this question has many questions around in Stackoverflow but even though it has many answers about it, thoses answers couldn't help me at all and either figured it out yet.

In my WebAPP it works normal, but when I transform it to an API it fails(topic title error)... I have tried following:

> save first Test(flush:true) // error the C must be NOT NULL
>
> save testInstance.addToAs(a).save() //b and c

Why I can't save the whole object?

Domain Water

```
static hasMany = [personWaters   : Person,
                  equipmentWaters: Equipment,
                  sampleWaters   : WaterSample]
```

Domain WaterSample

```
static belongsTo = [water: Water]
```

Controller refactored some parts

```
def save() {
    def waterParams = request.JSON
    def sampleList = [] as Set
    def equipmentList = [] as Set
    def personList = [] as Set

    waterAPIService.personPopulate(waterParams.personWaters, personList)
    waterAPIService.equipmentPopulate(waterParams.equipmentWaters, equipmentList)
    waterAPIService.samplePopulate(waterParams.sampleWaters, sampleList)

    Date validity = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", waterParams.validity)
    Date sample = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", waterParams.sampleDate)

    waterParams.remove('personWaters')
    waterParams.remove('equipmentWaters')
    waterParams.remove('sampleWaters')
    waterParams.remove('validity')
    waterParams.remove('sampleDate')

    waterParams.put('personWaters', personList)
    waterParams.put('equipmentWaters', equipmentList)
    waterParams.put('sampleWaters', sampleList)

    waterParams.put('validity', validity)
    waterParams.put('sampleDate', sample)

    def waterInstance = new Water(waterParams)

    //def test = waterAPIService.sampleValidated(sampleList ? sampleList.size() : 0, sampleList)
    def test = 99
    if (test == 99) {
        if (saveTest(waterInstance)) {
            render([message: ['ok']] as JSON)
        } else {
            def errors = []
            errors.add('Erro ao salvar')
            errors = waterInstance.errors.allErrors.collect { g.message([error: it]) }
            render([message: errors] as JSON)
        }
    } else {
        render render([message: ["Critério de estabilização não atendido para o parâmetro " + waterAPIService.messageSampleValidated(test)]] as JSON)
    }
}

def saveTest(Water waterInstance) {
    try {
        println waterInstance.validate()
        if (!waterInstance.hasErrors() && waterInstance.save() && waterInstance.validate()) {
            return true
        } else {
            log.info("error", waterInstance.errors)
            return false
        }
    } catch (e) {
        log.info("exception error", e)
    }
}
```

Service

```
def personPopulate(personWaters, personList) {
    personWaters.each {
        personList <<  Person.get(it.id)
    }
    return personList
}

def equipmentPopulate(equipmentWaters, equipmentList) {
    equipmentWaters.each {
        equipmentList << Equipment.get(it.id)
    }
    return equipmentList
}

def samplePopulate(sampleWaters, sampleList) {
    sampleWaters.each {
        def sample = new WaterSample()
        sample.dateTime = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", it.dateTime)
        sample.levelWater = it.levelWater
        sample.conductivity = it.conductivity
        sample.dissolvedOxygen = it.dissolvedOxygen
        sample.redoxPotential = it.redoxPotential
        sample.ph = it.ph
        sample.temperature = it.temperature
        sampleList << sample
    }
    return sampleList
}
```

waterParam JSON

```
{  
"climateCondition":"SUNNY",
"equipmentWaters":[  
   {  
      "id":2
   },
   {  
      "id":4
   }
],
"personWaters":[  
   {  
      "id":86
   },
   {  
      "id":143
   }
],
"sampleWaters":[  
   {  
      "ReportId":2,
      "conductivity":0,
      "IDWeb":0,
      "dissolvedOxygen":0,
      "dateTime":"2015-12-07T17:08:00Z",
      "levelWater":0,
      "ID":4,
      "UpdateDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "ph":0,
      "redoxPotential":0,
      "temperature":0
   },
   {  
      "ReportId":2,
      "conductivity":0,
      "IDWeb":0,
      "dissolvedOxygen":0,
      "dateTime":"2015-12-07T17:09:00Z",
      "levelWater":0,
      "ID":5,
      "UpdateDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "ph":0,
      "redoxPotential":0,
      "temperature":0
   },
   {  
      "ReportId":2,
      "conductivity":0,
      "IDWeb":0,
      "dissolvedOxygen":0,
      "dateTime":"2015-12-07T18:13:00Z",
      "levelWater":0,
      "ID":6,
      "UpdateDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "ph":0,
      "redoxPotential":0,
      "temperature":0
   }
]
}
```

Comment: fsi, that code is waaayyy to sanitized to be useful for troubleshooting. In other words, you removed too much of the code. For what it's worth, call `save()` (which calls `validate()`) prior to calling `hasErrors()`.

Comment: Updated, please check it out, I got the code

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could simplify the vast majority of this by relying on the built-in data binding; you are already using it but you are also manually parsing date fields and manipulating the JSON request.  What does your JSON look like?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was a headache to find one of the solution:

If you trying to save an object, debug your it and inspect any of nested objects, for example: I'm sending approval.id: null, the object will give me below:

"approval":{
      "class":"User",
      "id":null
   },

Which is trying to add a user with id null, whick wont find and wont save. So remove it from your json request.